# Shared style in custom element using Polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer

I am using the `polymer starter kit light` as a basis for my website.
To this website I added a custom element. Inside this element a checkbox is used. But I want to change the margins of the checkbox and I want to do this globally. I can change it using the local style:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-checkbox{
        margin-inside: 8px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        margin-right: 8px;
    }
</style>
```

But if I add it to `app-theme.html` provided by the starter kit and used as a global style, then the margins are not changed. I also do not know what the differences are between `app-theme.html` and `shared-styles.html`.

How can I add this change globally in the `polymer starter kit light`?

Comment: I think you should read the guide on [styling for polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) first since what you probably need is to use mixins

Comment: Mixins do work. But how can I change margins? They do not provide a mixins for that.

Comment: The purpose of mixins is for you to set any CSS properties all at once...

Comment: That is what I want to achieve and why I am asking the question. But there are no mixins for margins.